# Add button next page - wizard - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

I'm trying to create a wizard which has several pages.

I know how to pass to `'target'` new or current, to pass the action to a form or tree view, but what I actually need, before that, is to create several steps which will be on different "views" of this wizard, like a form with 'next' and 'back' buttons.

Is there some example code I can look for that?

I've searched on default addons, with no success.

Comment: if the nodestroy not done then you can close the new wizard, so can you see the previous one?

Comment: I mean this should be a multi step wizard, in which I can go back the previous step if needed.

Comment: you can achieve this by multi wizard. forward button will open new wizard, gave a backbutton which closes current node

Comment: if you need this on same screen, yhen you will need to extend view or use any iframes

Comment: Something like this? : https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-to-create-a-wizard-with-steps-19828

Comment: You can use `state` to visible or invisible a part of your view. So next step = next `state`.

Comment: @NeoVe Exactly and also you can use the concept of making readonly fields for next steps. But i think this should be difficult to implement. Do you best. cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have a popup `target=new` and have a `statusbar` on top right which will be clickable/not readonly (so that the user can go back). And depending on the state of your record, show the appropriate fields

You can of course create a popup, and when the user clicks next destroy that popup and create another one but that doesn't seem like a good idea to me.